# Hide Primary Key column in Create View in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model generated from Database(SQL Server) which contain attribute TaskPK(Primary Key and Auto Increment in SQL). When i generate a create view, this attribute also shown. But when i have a attribute ID(Primary Key and Auto Increment), this attribute not shown in create view but the value still exist.

How can do this to my TaskPK attribute ?

Pict View:[ViewCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlXS2.png) 
Pict Model: [Code Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JCMl.png)

Comment: Can you please post code samples in view and your model?

Comment: Here is View Code http://i.stack.imgur.com/TlXS2.png

Comment: Model Code http://i.stack.imgur.com/2JCMl.png

Comment: You can replace HiddenFor instead of EditFor for TaskPK in razor sentence

Comment: I did it, but get error "The TaskPK field is required".

Comment: You might want to add a data annotation on your TaskPK, like
`[Key]`

Comment: Yes.. Already did it.. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide some property in your view you can simply use this helper:

`@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.YourModelItem)`

So in your code you need to change:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskPK, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

to:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TaskPK, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: Already did it. But still get the error. "The TaskPK field is Required"

Comment: Are you sure you have set your "TaskPK" as primary key?  It seems that you didn't do that at all.

Comment: Yes i am sure. i already define it at Sql Management Studio..Sorry if i forgotten, TaskModel is in ViewModel class. The actual model that generates from sqlserver is in business object

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to write following code into your model to hide primary key field.

[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
Public int TaskPK{get;set;}

Comment: The TaskPk hidden in view, but i get the error "TaskPK field is required"